# Sort the TreeMap conditionally using Comparator

Tags: java, comparator, treemap

I want to sort the TreeMap in the given order.
if there is a '_' in the string, put at the end, or keep the added order.

```
 class Order implements Comparator<String> {
      @Override
      //This works but mess up the group order. For instance bbbb comes after 'aaaa' 
      //  instead of 'cccc'
      public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if(o1.contains("_")) {
          order = 1;
        }
        if(o2.contains("_")) {
          order = order == 1? 0: -1;
        }
        return order == 0 ? o1.compareTo(o2) : order;
      }
    }
    class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> treeMap= new TreeMap<>(new Order());
        signalTypeMap.put("ccc_aaaa", "test");
        signalTypeMap.put("aaaa", "test");
        signalTypeMap.put("cccc", "test");
        signalTypeMap.put("bbbb", "test");
        signalTypeMap.put("ccc", "test");
        signalTypeMap.put("c_a", "test");
      }
}
```

Finally, map should be in the following order.

```
{ aaaa=test, cccc=test bbbb=test, ccc=test, ccc_aaaa=test, c_a=test}
```

Comment: `Comparator.comparingBoolean(s -> s.contains("_")).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())`?

Comment: "Or keep the added order" TreeMap doesn't preserve insertion order. It only uses the comparator, and the comparator shouldn't know about insertion order.

Comment: @AndyTurner i don't see anything like comparingBoolean()

Comment: Too old java, then `Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.contains("_")? 1 : 0).thenComparing(Collator.getInstance(Locale.US))`. I advise to use a locale when there are special characters, so in German "Österreich" (Austria) is placed before "P"

Comment: @AndyTurner which version of Java has `comparingBoolean`?

Comment: @k314159 I'm just making up API methods again. I of course mean `Comparator.comparing(s -> s.contains("_"))`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to keep the same order but have the underscores at the end.  Although this operates on the existing map, the following will work. It uses a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the order.

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

map.put("ccc_aaaa", "test");
map.put("aaaa", "test");
map.put("cccc", "test");
map.put("bbbb", "test");
map.put("ccc", "test");
map.put("c_a", "test");
```

- first, iterate the entry set. Since elements will be removed from the map, you need to iterate over a copy so you don't get `modification exceptions`.
- If the key as an underscore, delete it and then add it back in. It will now be at the end in its original relative order of underscored keys.
- Otherwise, just ignore the entry.

```
for (Entry<String, String> entry : new LinkedHashMap<>(map)
        .entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    if (key.contains("_")) {
        map.remove(key);
        map.put(key, entry.getValue());
    }
}

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
aaaa=test
cccc=test
bbbb=test
ccc=test
ccc_aaaa=test
c_a=test
```

Answer (score 0):

In your comparator, you're not checking if there is a `_` in the input strings. Then you can return 1, 0, -1 depending on the other string being compared to.

In order to have `cccc` before the `bbbb` you'll need to define your own rules. The default will sort the input strings lexographically.